# Pllaying Audio when clicked on image in HTML5 with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, audio

So, Guys I have an issue here, I need to play an audio when someone click on an image i tried with Jplayer but i failed miserably, I need to play audio on mobile with cordova so it has to be an internel player and also when clicked on another file the first audio should stop; so i need your help Guys here is Html code

```
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="track"
                    data-mp3="audio/01.mp3" > 
                    <img src="images/01.jpg" /><div><h3>Urra</h3></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/02.jpg" /><div><h3></h3></div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/03.jpg" /><div><h3></h3></div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/04.jpg" /><div><h3></h3></div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/05.jpg" /><div><h3></h3></div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/06.jpg" /><div><h3></h3></div></a></li>
```

so it's not working like this

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("a.track").live("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", 
                    { 
                        mp3: $(this).attr("data-mp3"), 
                        oga: $(this).attr("data-ogg") 
                    })
                    .jPlayer("play");
            });
        </script>
```